# Trouble reindexing - forgein key constrain fails

Tags: database, reindex, indexer

I deleted all products by truncating tables. 
Now, after uploading all products again I get this:

```
    Product Attributes index process unknown error:

    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity 
constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
 constraint fails (`XXXXXX`.`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT 
`FK_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
(`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE 
CASCA)'
```

How can I repiar the database now so eindex is working again? How can I find the right entities to delete?

Comment: Have you cleared cache and your Locks directory in the var folder?

Comment: What has this to do with an Database error while reindexing from the shell? The Error comes clearly from database.

Comment: Because I have had the same error and clearing the cache and locks folder and solved it

Comment: I strongly doubt that.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking around a litte - not so easy to find but here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111889/cant-re-index-new-products-after-upgrading-to-version-1-6/19837851#19837851